# How to access sharepoint data to asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, csom

I'm currently developing a website using asp.net that should be connected to sharepoint and access its data and files, right now I'm trying the CSOM(Client Side- Object Model). But I'm getting an error when tried to access the URL.

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

Here's my code:

```
SPClient.ClientContext ctx = new SPClient.ClientContext("Site URL");
        SPClient.Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
        ctx.Load(myWeb, w => w.Title);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Response.Write(myWeb.Title);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set credential for your request.

SharePoint on-premise:

```
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
```

SharePoint online:

```
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);
```